# Why don't code snippets work for me in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to use the simple pre-installed code snippets in VS2008.  I can insert them by right-clicking and using Insert Snippet..., but I can't get them to work while typing.  If I start to type "for", I get the Intellisense list, and I see an entry for the code snippet, but hitting Tab or Enter just inserts the word for, not the snippet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try hitting tab once more..

Answer (score 0):

Or in *Emacs* style

```
ctrl-k ctrl-x
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your using any kind of VPC software that is intercepting your tab commands and inject them into VPC with a wrong code. I havent found a solution yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Which language you are using?

C++ snippets don't work in VS2008. [MS took](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361639) that feature out :(